# Include a database .h file in the factory or in the class in C++

Tags: c++, header-files, dependency-management

I have a factory, GuiTable.cpp where I create multiple GUI-related classes. I also have a database class, `CommonStrDatabase.h` which serves as a database file for different strings used in the GUI. 
One of the classes I create in the factory looks like this:

```
#include "display/DisplayMenu.h"

#include "CommonStrDatabase.h"

namespace gui{
namespace display{

DisplayMenu::DisplayMenu(MenuID Id, MyProcess* OwnerProc)
: Menu(Id, STRING_DIAGMENU, OwnerProc)
{
    Layout layout( paramText,
                   paramTop,
                   paramWidth,
                   setParamtHeight );

    int row = 0;
    layout.addGraphicalControl(row++, 0, new StrView(DEV, OwnerProc, "Close menu" , 0, 0, TEXTALIGN_L, TextFont));

...
}
```

The parameter `STRING_DIAGMENU` is a string(actually a typedef but does not matter here) which comes from `CommonStrDatabase.h`. My question: is it better to include the database file as I did here, or would you include it in the factory, and then pass the string as a parameter to the `DisplayMenu`, like this:

```
#include "display/DisplayMenu.h"
#include <string>

namespace gui{
namespace display{

DisplayMenu::DisplayMenu(MenuID Id, MyProcess* OwnerProc, string DiagMenuString)
: Menu(Id, DiagMenuString, OwnerProc)
{
    Layout layout( paramText,
                   paramTop,
                   paramWidth,
                   setParamtHeight );

    int row = 0;
    layout.addGraphicalControl(row++, 0, new StrView(DEV, OwnerProc, "Close menu" , 0, 0, TEXTALIGN_L, TextFont));

...
}
```

I suppose it is better to include the database file in one place, in the factory, otherwise you would have to include it in every class which uses it? Will multiple includes make the compilation time slower, even if you use `#pragma once` in `CommonStrDatabase.h`?

Comment: You probably should post this in [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is that `DiagMenuString` going to have the same value for every `DisiplayMenu` object, or can it have different values for different objects?

Comment: Different value for different objects. However, I am not sure if more objects will use it, but it may very well be so in the future when I add new gui-components to the factory.

Comment: @Rosme I think it’s the right place here: this is really a practical issue about writing c++ code and not really a software engineering question

Answer (score 0):

There are a [couple of recommendations](http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/CppHeaderFileGuidelines.pdf) to follow about managing dependencies and headers.

First of all, your header for the factory should be self sufficient: if someone wants only the factory, he or she shall be able to rely on the completeness of your header.  So if your factory needs additional headers, include the in the factory header. That’s guideline 9 of the hyperlink above. And that’s also [a core c++ guideline](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rs-contained).

Proper dependency management requires that you think ahead of what would happen if you would change the database: if in some cpp that also uses the factory would rely on database.h hot just because of the factory header, but because it actively uses elements of the database, independently of the factory, then include the database.h. explicitly. That’s guideline 1 and 13 of the hyperlinked document. And it’s also a [core guideline](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rs-consistency).

Finally, you need include guard in your headers. Of course `#pragma once` is nice. But it’s not portable. Therefore the [c++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rs-guards) recommend not to use it.